# stretch div vertically

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement cosntruction, described [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xyp4j/).

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
        header
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        main<br/>main<br/>main<br/>main<br/>main<br/>main<br/>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    footer
</div>​

#header {
    border-top:20px solid #fff;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
html { height: 100%; }
body { height: 100%; width: 90%; margin: auto; }
#wrap { min-height: 100%;background-color:gray;}
#main {
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 53px; /* must be same height as the footer */
    background-color: red;
    border: solid 1px blue;
    height: 90%;
}
#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -53px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    border-bottom:20px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

​

The whole page has background color (gray), header and footer are transparent (so you can see the page's background through it) and the content block has red background. Despite the fact that content part is stretchable it doesn't fill with the background the whole block, only the actual.

1. Is it possible to fill the whole content block with the color?
2. While minimizing window the footer floats on content. is it possible to disable such behaviour?

Comment: Hi! Could you perhaps add some sample code? Links are best for *support* only, so that the question will make sense to future users even if the linked site moves/dies. Thx!

Comment: You can see the link to sample code at the first line of my question

Comment: I know, but links are best used only for *supporting* the question. The question in itself is better if future users can view and use it even if the linked site [has moved or changed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkrot).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/xyp4j/32/)** is a workaround of what you are looking for. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!! That's what I am looking for. But one more question - is it possible to add the scrollbar (while minimizing) to page and not to content block?

Comment: Than it always shows the scrollbars. I mean only while minimizing. Like in your example but instead of inner scrollbar (of content block)  I want to see the window scrollbar

Comment: what do u mean my `minimizing`? A browser window resizing?

Comment: By the way, in your solution the footer has a background color. And I need it transparent because I have some backgrond picture for whole page

Comment: its complex. I recommend to keep `overflow: scroll;` to `#main` so that header and footer will remain in their place

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines of code below to your code:

```
#main{
  position: absolute;
  top: 33px;
  bottom: 33px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#wrap{
  position: relative;
}
```